# Making the application close normally after printing Assertion Error

Tags: c#, c, assert

In C program i'm trying to test a few conditions in assert(). 
The problem i'm facing is, The program crashes after printing the error message. I dont want that, I want the application to exit normally after printing the error message as i wanna link this program further to another C# program and I dont want that crash prompt to be displayed for a background process. Need help!

```
asssert(10 == func(<some input>));
```

I'm using this to check whether the written function by user returns the expected answer or not. When it returns correct answer its okay. but when wrong answer is received, I've to mark in the database that wrong answer is obtained. But the program crashes and the assertionError is neither in StandardError nor in StandardOutput

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: thats not what assert is used for. assert should only be used for debugging, and every failed assertion should be a fatal error.

Comment: i've edited my post a little!

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to create your own function or preprocessor macro.

When you call assert(), the meaning is "the following expression *must* be true, otherwise the program has entered a fatally corrupt state".  The response, therefore, is to terminate it, leaving a core dump which you can hopefully use to inspect the program's variables and fix the bug which led to the failed assertion.

Handling user input gracefully is a completely different task, not at all appropriate for assert().  Among other reasons, assert() does strictly nothing in programs compiled as release builds, so you should not be relying on it for your program's actual functionality.